# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2\pi t) \frac{(t-1)(t-2)}{\left[(t-1)^2-9\right][(t-2)^2-49/4]}dt\neq 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2\pi t) \frac{(t-1)(t-2)}{\left[(t-1)^2-9\right][(t-2)^2-49/4]}dt\neq 0$$
I tried to solve this integral but I think it does not admit closed form solution. There must be another way to prove the statement. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It would have been surprizing that the monster exhibits a closed form solution ! Sorry for no suggestion. I am stuck too.

Comment: ... the values is $-\frac{72}{55}\pi$

Comment: @Math-fun. Yes, I got this one. It is funny how are simple the integrals of each term after partial fraction decomposition. May I ask how you got the result (may be a different way). Cheers :-)

Comment: I also find it intriguing! ... I was doing a partial fraction while your answer appeared :-) Thanks for the message.

Comment: You can integrate this also straightforwardly by residue theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment*

I do not see why the integral could be $0$ : no symetry, very different vertical asymptotes.

Anyway, what I suggest is  that you use partial fraction decomposition to get $$\frac{(t-2) (t-1)}{\left((t-2)^2-\frac{49}{4}\right) \left((t-1)^2-9\right)}=-\frac{8}{15 (t+2)}+\frac{2}{5 (2 t-11)}+\frac{10}{11 (2 t+3)}-\frac{4}{33 (t-4)}$$ and then use $$\int \frac {\sin(2\pi t)}{t+a}=\cos (2 \pi  a) \text{Si}(2 \pi  (a+t))-\sin (2 \pi  a) \text{Ci}(2 \pi  (a+t))$$ where appear the sine and cosine integrals.

**Edit**

The most funny is that, after partial fraction decomposition, each integral has a very simple value (I let you the pleasure of finding them).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I try to calculate these integrals.

Comment: They are very simple. Make the appropriate change of variable to have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{\sin(x)}x dx$ for which the result is just $\pi$.

Comment: So good! Thanks!